# How can I efficiently translate "terrain" numpy array into networkx graph?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures, graph

I have a 2d boolean numpy array A. Each element is a pixel of the map with True corresponding to terrain, and False corresponding to water. Say, I want to check how many different continents I have, so I want to use networx.number_connected_components(G)

I can build the graph G manually iterating over elements of array A and checking whether pieces of land are connected or not (pixels are considered connected only if they have a common edge, so each pixel of land can be connected at most to 4, and no diagonal connections are allowed).

But this strikes my as inefficient and unpythonic. How can I do better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify and count the number of connected regions, you can use [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) (so you don't need networkx).  For example,

```
In [73]: x
Out[73]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [74]: from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label

In [75]: labeled_x, num_labels = label(x)

In [76]: num_labels
Out[76]: 8

In [77]: labeled_x
Out[77]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 6, 6, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

(In the example, `x` is an array of 0s and 1s, but `label` also accepts a boolean array.)